# Custom UIBarButtonItem back button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to customize UIBarButtonItem back button so it is displayed with a simple arrow icon (like in Facebook, Twitter etc). Do I need to create a custom UIBarButtonItem and manually add it to the nav bar or is there a way to do this through appearance API?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make your own and add it

You can do it like this (this is for a custom button using an image)

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"];
    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);

    UIButton *someButton2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
    [someButton2 setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(loadFavorites)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someButton2 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *favoritesButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton2];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:favoritesButton, nil];
```

Comment: The other way you could do this is follow what waf says above, but set it to `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in your view controller's init method. Just realize that this property (unlike `rightBarButtonItem`) will set the style for controllers pushed onto your view controller, whereas `rightBarButtonItem` places a button in your view controller. The advantage is that you don't need to check if you actually can go back, the nav controller will still do that for you.

Comment: @axiixc Sounds good. I tried it, didn't get it working. It will be helpful if you post your solution here as an edit or as new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that you can't actually use `backBarButtonItem` with a `UIBarButtonItem` created with a custom view. The best I can offer is you can create a template with an image and a empty background image, although it feels a bit like spacer.gif. I threw together a quick example to show what I meant about the view controller ordering too.

http://cl.ly/36091p0l0120